# Controlling if VSCode build tasks run in parallel

Tags: vscode-tasks

It used to be that when I hit "ctrl+shift+b" to start a build task while another was running, vscode would pop up a message when the current task is still running. Recently, this behavior stopped and instead the build gets invoked again, resulting in multiple builds at the same time.

Is there any way to control this behavior to get one task?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is just a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96959